# Ajax : empty json response when using Karma

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox, karma-runner

**TL;DR** : Does [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) tamper with ajax request sent while running tests ?

---

## Context

I'm currently writing unit-tests for a front-end javascript application. I'm using [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) 0.12.31 to run the tests and the only frontend library I use that is relevant to this question is jQuery.

I have a really simple class object responsible for fetching and caching results from a backend API :

```
function APIReader(baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.cache = {};
}
APIReader.prototype.updateCache = function(uuid) {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url : this.baseUrl+uuid,
        dataType : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function (data) {
            that.cache[uuid] = data;
        },
        error : function(jqxhr, status, err) {
            that.cache[uuid] = undefined;
        }
    });
};
APIReader.prototype.get = function(uuid) {
    if (!(uuid in this.cache)) this.updateCache(uuid);
    return this.cache[uuid];
};
```

The following snippet works like a charm on the development server :

```
var ar = new APIReader('http://server/api/endpoint/');
console.log(ar.get('18fc7dc1-7698-4b8e-900e-8262c1393067'));
```

## Issue

However, when testing this with Karma using, say :

```
it('should work', function() {
    var ar = new APIReader('http://server/api/endpoint/');
    expect(ar.get('some-uuid')).toEqual({
        ... some object ...
    });
});
```

I get this error : `1) Expected null to be Object({ ... some object ... }).`.

I've looked into it for a while and it seems the body of the ajax response received by the browser (Firefox 35) is empty.

[image: Empty JSON in Firefox]

I'm pretty sure the API (written with [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)) works well as [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) gives the correct (non-enpty) result for the same endpoint.

I've actually gone as far as to reproduce the exact same headers that Firefox uses using cURL :

[image: Firefox cURL]

And this returned the correct result as well.

## Summing up

- I'm pretty confident the API is working well
- I'm confident the `APIReader` snippet works well (there's not much to it and it gives the correct results in dev)
- I *suppose* there's something in Karma tampering  with ajax requests (wiping the body or something) but there isn't much documentation available on their [website](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) and I couldn't find anything like that.

Any clue as to what's happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** : CORS.

It seems all this was because the API server didn't allow the test server to to do cross-origin requests.

The django app (API) uses [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) to generate CORS headers. What I hadn't realized is that there's a distinction on host based on ports :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost',
    'other-domain',
)
```

doesn't allow the test server running on `localhost:4000` to send CORS requests. I had to add the following :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost',
    'other-domain',
    'localhost:4000' # Karma test
)
```

It now works as expected.